# Are there elements in $^$ that aren't games?

Tags: combinatorial-game-theory, surreal-numbers

The text bellow is just an explanation of the title, if you understood the title you don't have to read the text.

Games are defined by the rule "If L and R are two sets of games, then { L | R } is a game". If we also add the rule "Each element of L must be strictly less than each element of R", then we get the surreal numbers, $$. By adding this rule, we loose some games, e.g $$ and $*$ are games that aren't in $$.

There are gaps in $$ and the completion of $$ is called $^$(see link at bottom for clarification). When you construct $^$ you get back some of the games you lost when you constructed $$. $$ is an example of a game that is also in $^$($*$ however is not in $^$).

My question is this: Do you get any brand new elements when you construct $^$, elements that weren't games first?

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surreal_number#Gaps_and_continuity

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the question, it was written that "$\mathbf{On}$ and $*$ are games", but $\mathbf{On}$ is a gap that is not a game, because you can't get something equal to $\mathbf{On}$ with mere sets (as opposed to proper classes) in the left and right positions.

Any game with sets in the left and right positions is less than, say, the game/surreal $x=\{\kappa^+|\,\}$ where $\kappa$ is the cardinality for the depth of the game tree. And $x<\mathbf{On}$.

The gap $\infty$ mentioned in the wikipedia page is *also* not equal to a game, but that's less immediate.

(Also, readers should be careful not to confuse the gap $\mathbf{On}=\{\mathbf{No}|\,\}$ with the loopy game $\mathrm{on}=\{\mathrm{on}|\,\}$.)

Comment: so both the examples wikipedia had for gaps weren't games after all, does there exist any gap you can show as equivalent to a game then?
Also im not sure what the superscript "+" notation mean here. And yes, I did not notice the loopy game "on" had a lower case o while the gap "On" had a capital O, so I thought they were the same game/gap. But they still behave similar, right? e.g on+x=on  and On+x=On if x is surreal. also they are the largest element in their respective class. Can you combine games with gaps at all, or does that not work out?

Comment: @Mettek 1. No, I don't think any gap is equal to a game. 2. + denotes [successor cardinal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Successor_cardinal). 3. Those equations are similar, yes. But it could be argued that $\mathrm{on}>\mathbf{On}$. 4. What do you mean by "combine games with gaps"? You could certainly add a game and a gap and play it.

Comment: "Combine" is probally the wrong term, but yes, I meant if it made sense to use games and gaps together, i.e add them, compare them, etc, so your reply answers that. I still have some trouble understanding why {L|R} < {$\kappa^+$|}, if e.g x={7,3|}=8, then L∪U = {7,3}, the cardinality of that set is 2, so $\kappa^+$ is 3, but {3|}=4, which is less then 8. I'm sure I have misunderstood something, just not sure what it is. Thanks for answering all my previous questions

Comment: @Mettek, good point. The thing I wrote originally was blatantly wrong for the reason you mention. I must have been trying to hastily write something like "the union of those unions for all subpositions (or followers?) of the position", but the depth of the game tree suffices. Will edit now.

Comment: "The gap ∞ mentioned in the wikipedia page is also not equal to a game, but that's less immediate."

I noticed that "On Numbers And Games" uses the "∞" symbol for both that gap, and the game R||R|R. So just to be clear, these objects are not equal to each other?

Comment: @Mettek, Correct: The gap $\infty$ refers to something like $\{\mathbb{R}\mid \text{[the proper Class of all positive infinite/large surreals]}\}$. But the game $\infty=\{\mathbb R\,\,\Vert\,\,\mathbb R\mid\mathbb R\}$ only uses sets in its construction, and its left and right sets of games do not obey the inequalities to make it a surreal. The game "lies in" the gap (in the sense of ONAG) because it has the same order relations to all surreals.